# News System issue (Php and Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm creating a news system for my website. What I have is a main page {index.php} (where all the articles are shown) and an article page (article.php)

What I'm having trouble with is having content selected on the article page.

When you click on the title on the index.php I want it to go to the article.php and show that articles information (currently achieved through get articleID)...

When you click the category of the article, I want it to go to article.php and show ALL the articles with the same category

How can I set up my code to accomplish this?

Currently I have for the article.php page

```
if( isset($_GET['category']) ){
  $subject= $_GET['category'];
} else {
  $subject= $_GET['id'];
}

$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category="$subject"');

while($row = $STH->fetch()) { 
  echo $row['content'];
}
```

For the index.php page I call the category through this

```
echo '<a class="post-type" href="articles.php?category='.$row['category'].'">'. $row['category'] .'</a>';
```

Comment: Does your articles page actually work? If so - what SQL library you are using? I've been thinking of such syntax only yesterday. But more likely it seems you just messed up quotes and totally misuse your SQL lib. and it should be `$DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category=?',$subject);` or something.

Comment: A logic seems strange a bit. How come you have both category and id in the same `category` field?

Comment: I'm using PDO to achieve this - the page works. The quotes have been changed and everythings working now per Aqeel Ahmads recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well You're missing a bit of thing here. Actually you need three pages, not two. One page is index.php which actually shows up all the latest content (articles). Other one page is to show single article (article.php), the third page is articles.php or category.php, this page will show the articles like index.php page but of particular category.

Note: You can manage with two pages as well but you'll have to manage your article.php for two different layouts, one is single article and other is article list like index.php page. So i suggest to have articles.php or category.php as a seperate page.